# SQL Server 2019 setting Force Encryption with a script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, encryption, sql-server-2019, configuration-manager

I have to update 50+ servers to use encrypted connection strings. Is there a way to script setting Force Encryption and TrustServerCertificate (e.g Powershell, or ???) so that I don't have to open Configuration Manager and set on each box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use dbatools in particular the command Enable-DbaForceNetworkEncryption

Comment: While DbaTools works I need a solution using PowerShell for circumstances where a client won't allow the installation of DbaTools on their jump box.

Comment: As they publish all of their source code on github you could perhaps open the files and look at the powershell they are using